# radio button groups nested inside checkbox list with angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

In this example I'm nesting radio buttons inside checkboxes:

html:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <div name="myForm">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model='item.selected' />{{item.name}}</label>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="format in item.formats">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" ng-model='format.selected' name='what name ?'/>{{format.title}}</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <button ng-click='onClick()'>Go</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
function Controller($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
        name: 'cb1',
        selected:false,
        formats: [{
            title: 'rb1a',
            selected: false
        }, {
            title: 'rb1b ',
            selected: false
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'cb2 ',
        selected:false,
        formats: [{
            title: 'rb2a ',
            selected: false
        }, {
            title: 'rb2b',
            selected: false
        }]
    }];

    $scope.onClick = function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.items[i].selected) {
                console.log('Controller item selected', $scope.items[i]);
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.items[i].formats.length; j++) {
                if ($scope.items[i].formats[j].selected) 
                    console.log('Controller format selected', $scope.items[i].formats[j]);
            }
        }

    };

};
```

I have two questions:

- when I select an rb in one group the selected rb in the other group gets unselected. So they are not groups yet. How can I make real groups? I thought by using the name directive, but how?
- when I click the Go button I'd like to have set the selected properties in $scope.items correctly, both for checkboxes and radio buttons.

I tried a lot already, that's why I'm now just providing stripped down code.

http://jsfiddle.net/JeffW/crn1t7wy/

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to set the name to be unique for each group of radio buttons. You can do it with the $index argument angular provides with ng-repeat.

2) You misplaced single quotes and this is why it doesn't work. HTML accepts only double quotes or single quotes as attribute values but not mixed.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <div name="myForm">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model='item.selected' />{{item.name}}</label>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="format in item.formats">
                        <label> 
                            <input type="radio" ng-value="format.title" ng-model="item.selectedRadio" name="myName{{$parent.$index}}"/>{{format.title}}</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button ng-click='onClick()'>Go</button>
</div>
```

Fixed version is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/crn1t7wy/3/

EDIT: Fixed the answer based on the comments

Comment: thanks, the groups are now isolated. Are you sure about the necessity of double quotes btw? Anyway, when I select a radio button and then select another one in the same group, their selected properties are both set to true. Why don't they jump back to false through their model when unselected again?

Comment: Actually you are right, single quotes are allowed but not a mix of single and double quotes. My answer tried to stick to your original code but actually you need to map all the radio buttons to the same model.